# log when countDownLatch.await() times out

Tags: java

I am using Java's CountDownLatch with a timeout, something like the below in my integration  tests:

```
countDownLatch.await( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

At times, the countDownLatch.countdown() call is not made and countDownLatch.await(..) times out. I want to log whenever that happens to help me in debugging my failing tests. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

From the doc on CountDownLatch.await:  "If the specified waiting time elapses then the value false is returned. If the time is less than or equal to zero, the method will not wait at all."

```
try (
  if (!countDownLatch.await( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    // Log that countDownLatch timed out
  }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
  // Log interrupted by another thread.
}
```